# Multiple IF in Mysql Trigger is not working

Tags: php, mysql, triggers

I'm trying to log changes of a table into another table. But my trigger is not working. Need help:

```
// Mysql code below
create trigger upd_stu_info
before update
on kisalg_student
for each row
    begin
        IF OLD.stu_name != NEW.stu_name
        THEN
        INSERT INTO `kisalg_logactions`
        (adm_no, change_type,change_head, old_value,new_value,user,date_time,session)
        VALUES 
        (NEW.adm_no, 'stu_info','Change In Student Name ', OLD.stu_name, NEW.stu_name, NEW.user, NEW.date_time, NEW.session);
        END IF;

        IF OLD.fat_name != NEW.fat_name
        THEN
        INSERT INTO `kisalg_logactions`
        (adm_no, change_type, change_head, old_value, new_value, user, date_time, session)
        VALUES 
        (NEW.adm_no, 'stu_info','Change In Father Name ', OLD.fat_name, NEW.fat_name, NEW.user, NEW.date_time, NEW.session);
        END IF;  
    end;
```

Comment: What, exactly, is not working? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 11

Comment: You need delimiter set at the beginning `delimiter //` and at the end `//`

Comment: (NEW.adm_no, 'stu_info','Change In Student Name ', OLD.stu_name, NEW.stu_name, NEW.user, NEW.date_time, NEW.session);

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty can you write complete query. I am executing this on phpmyadmin.

Comment: @vitorio just answered another trigger related answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25844933/mysql-inserting-row-in-table-1-when-specific-row-deleted-on-table-2/25845052#25845052, check the example how delimiter is added.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty my query has multiple if conditions. It is working with one IF condition but not on more than one If conditions. It is showing SYNTAX ERROR. Can you try it on your phpmyadmin if you can.

Comment: @vitorio Check my answer, I tried your trigger and it worked the way I have in answer.

Comment: Also if you still get syntax error please post the error in to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried the trigger on mysql and using the following I did not get any syntax error

```
delimiter //
create trigger upd_stu_info
before update
on kisalg_student
for each row
    begin
        IF OLD.stu_name != NEW.stu_name
         THEN
            INSERT INTO `kisalg_logactions`
            (adm_no, change_type,change_head, old_value,new_value,user,date_time,session)
            VALUES 
            (NEW.adm_no, 'stu_info','Change In Student Name ', OLD.stu_name, NEW.stu_name, NEW.user, NEW.date_time, NEW.session);
        END IF;

        IF OLD.fat_name != NEW.fat_name
          THEN
            INSERT INTO `kisalg_logactions`
            (adm_no, change_type, change_head, old_value, new_value, `user`, date_time, session)
            VALUES 
            (NEW.adm_no, 'stu_info','Change In Father Name ', OLD.fat_name, NEW.fat_name, NEW.`user`, NEW.date_time, NEW.session);
        END IF;  
    end; //
```

Comment: Not sure why you are getting the error, it works pretty well when I try on mysql terminal. In PhpMyadmin as far as I know needs delimiter (not used for really long time).

Comment: don't know what is the problem. It get me stucked in middle of my project. And Multiple instances of trigger is not permissible for one table.

Comment: If you have mysql terminal try the same above trigger in there. I personally do not encourage phpmyadmin for these things.

Comment: **ERROR 1235 (42000): This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'multiple triggers with the same action time and event for one table'.** On the terminal as I was thinking.

Comment: hmm looks like you have multiple trigger on the same table for same action, you can not have that. Check the existing triggers. If there is a duplicate one then drop the duplicate one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61345/discussion-between-vitorio-and-abhik-chakraborty).